# GraphQl just return raw data

Tags: typescript, graphql

I use GraphQL.
That's query, that I use:

```
query Query {
  GetPing {
    ping
  }
}
```

I except get something like this:

```
{
    ping: pong
}
```

But I get that:

```
{
  "data": {
    "GetPing": {
      "ping": "pong"
    }
  }
}
```

Graphgl just return raw data without any processing. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The response you are seeing is in the expected format as outlined in the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Response-Format). The actual data is wrapped inside a `data` property because any errors will be returned separately from the data:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors" [
    {
      "message": "Oh no! Something went wrong!"
    }
  ]
}
```

GraphQL supports partial responses, so it's possible to have some data returned along with an array of errors.

`GetPing` is also a necessary part of the response. `GetPing` is a field on your `Query` type. You could request any number of other fields as well:

```
query {
  getPing {
    ping
  }
  getFoo {
    foo
  }
}
```

If multiple fields were requested, it wouldn't make sense to somehow flatten the data structure to just the child fields -- you'd want to know which child field belonged to which root field.